# Add items to bottom of Recycler View

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

Code of the illustration:

```
mLinearLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this);
mLinearLayoutManager.setReverseLayout(true);
mLinearLayoutManager.setStackFromEnd(true);
mMessageRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(mLinearLayoutManager);
```

[See illustration here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gZlBt.jpg)

How can I add new items (in my case, messages) to the **bottom** of Recycler View and still keep the "gravity" of the view to the top?

So, what works now is the following:

- The gravity of the view is at the top. That's good! ✓

What doesn't work:

- New messages are added to the top of the view. That's bad × 
  I want them to be added at the bottom of the view (after the previous message) like so:
  [See here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/F7hcg.gif)

Comment: probably reverse the list of objects you have, pass it again to the adapter and call notifyDataSetChanged()

Comment: did you tried notifyDataSetChanged,When the arraylist value is chaged you have to call notifyDataSetChanged,like this adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

Comment: @Gowthaman can you please provide more context in an answer?

Comment: @Ashish can you give more details in an answer?

Comment: @user8618899 post your code what u tried

Comment: @Gowthaman I didn't understand your comment, please give more context.

Comment: post your Adapter class code,

Comment: @Gowthaman I am using `FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<FriendlyMessage, MessageViewHolder> mFirebaseAdapter;`

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Try removing these two lines or setting them `false`

```
layoutManager.setReverseLayout(true);
layoutManager.setStackFromEnd(true);
```

`setStackFromEnd` will set the view to show the last element, the layout direction will remain the same whereas `setReverseLayout` will change the order of the elements added by the Adapter.

Try using this to move your `RecyclerView` and `EditText` up when keyboard appears

```
<activity name="YourActivity"
          android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden|adjustResize">
          //stateHidden -> keyboard is hidden when you first open the activity
          //adjustResize -> this will adjust the layout resize option
 ...
</activity>
```

in `AndroidManifest.xml`.

To hook the RecyclerView at top

```
    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
    android:id="@+id/messageRecyclerViewRep"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_below="@+id/linearLayout3"
    android:layout_marginLeft="36dp"
    android:scrollbars="vertical" />
```

To put the recyclerView at bottom first and push it up as the keyboard pops up.

```
 <LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/recyclerContainer"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_below="@+id/linearLayout3"
    android:layout_above="@+id/linearLayout"
    android:gravity="bottom">
    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/messageRecyclerViewRep"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="36dp"
        android:scrollbars="vertical" />
</LinearLayout>
```

To scroll the recyclerView to bottom when keyboard pops up i.e. when the recycler view's layout is changed ( You can do the same thing on Edit Text  active or focused or clicked or something like that. I've done it on recycler view's layout change. )

```
   recyclerView.addOnLayoutChangeListener(new View.OnLayoutChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onLayoutChange(View v, int left, int top, int right, int bottom, int oldLeft, int oldTop, int oldRight, int oldBottom) {
                if (bottom < oldBottom) {
                    recyclerView.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                            recyclerView.smoothScrollToPosition(mAdapter.getItemCount());
                        }
                    }, 100);
                }
            }
        });
```

Comment: I don't who deleted the he previous comments but here's my XML file again: https://pastebin.com/XGrN5Dsj

Comment: The bounty will be awarded once the asker's problem is resolved.

Comment: The issue is still not fixed.

Comment: I want when the soft keyboard pops up, the RecyclerView to pushed also.

Comment: Did you tried the edited one. Man, why don't you experiment your xml! Just take your time.

Comment: Yes, I did. It doesn't push the RecyclerView view up when the keyboard pops up.

Comment: This answer works very well. The only thing missing according to the asker is that the RecyclerView also has to pushed up when the soft keyboard appears. Currently, only the EditText gets pushed and not the RecyclerView. - I am the bounty holder.

Comment: The RecyclerView is always at top.

Comment: The messages of the RecyclerView do not get pushed up when the keyboard pops up

Comment: Does the last message appear  when the keyboard pops up? So, you want the recyclerView at bottom first but when the keyboard pops up, you want to push it up. Is it that?

Comment: Yes, that's it I think. Now, when the keyboard pops up, the last messages are not visible because the keyboard is **over** them.

Comment: Have you used this "layoutManager.setStackFromEnd(true);"?

Comment: Yes, but that makes the gravity of the RecyclerView to be at the bottom!

Comment: See, there are two things 1)Pushing the recyclerView up on keyboard pop up 2)Scrolling the recyclerView to bottom on keyboard pop up. If you are talking about  1* I'll test it for you and post it in my next edit. and  If you are talking about  2* "layoutManager.setStackFromEnd(true); will work unless you scroll recyclerView a bit up and cliked on the EditText after that". To scroll the recyclerView to bottom everytime you clicked on Edittext you should handle that when onClick/onActive(whatever) on EditText is triggred.

Comment: No layoutManager.setStackFromEnd(true); doesn't makes the gravity of the RecyclerView to be at the bottom. It just makes the RecyclerView scroll up i.e. to bottom, everytime you call notifyDataSetChanged() or any other notify function.

Comment: I already did it. Check the answer. And I've a question. What is that LinearLayout (with CircleImageView and some TextViews) for, there in your xml?

Comment: Still not working. What I mean by RecyclerView gravity should have on top: https://i.imgur.com/oA9kJiH.gif

Comment: What I mean when RecyclerView should be pushed up along with the soft keyboard: https://i.imgur.com/AI1BXrJ.gif

Comment: This is the asker's current situation with your code: https://imgur.com/a/0yttk (repost) The RecyclerView's messages get "cropped out" when the keyboard pops up...

Comment: From previous comment, you were talking about 2*. And for that "layoutManager.setStackFromEnd(true); will work for the first time the view is created or after some notifying action, and unless you scroll recyclerView a bit up and cliked on the EditText after that". To scroll the recyclerView to bottom everytime you clicked on Edittext you should handle that when onClick/onActive(whatever) on EditText is triggred. It should be done in java.

Comment: This is what setStackFromEnd(true) does: https://i.imgur.com/DwXzNYs.gif It makes the gravity of the RecyclerView be at the bottom. I don't want that. I want it at the top like this: https://i.imgur.com/sU42ELY.gif

Answer (score 6):

[setReverseLayout(true)](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/LinearLayoutManager.html#setReverseLayout(boolean)) this will reverse the item traversal & layout order.The first item will come to end not view or content.

[setStackFromEnd(true)](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/LinearLayoutManager.html#setStackFromEnd(boolean))  this will fill the recycler list content starting from the bottom of the view.

Need to `setStackFromEnd(true)` not `setReverseLayout(true)`

And in XML Recyclerview height should be `match_parent`

Below i have given working code.

**activity xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnAdd"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Add" />

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/rcList"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:clipToPadding="true" />


</LinearLayout>
```

**list item xml layout**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
    android:gravity="center_vertical">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:textSize="23sp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:textColor="#4a4883"
        android:text="Test Text" />
</FrameLayout>
```

**Adapter class**

```
public class CustomAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<CustomAdapter.ViewHolder> {
    private static final String TAG = "CustomAdapter";

    private ArrayList<String> mDataSet;
    private int size = 0;


    public static class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        private final TextView textView;

        public ViewHolder(View v) {
            super(v);
            v.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    Log.d(TAG, "Element " + getAdapterPosition() + " clicked.");
                }
            });
            textView = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.textView);
        }

        public TextView getTextView() {
            return textView;
        }
    }


    public CustomAdapter(ArrayList<String> dataSet) {
        mDataSet = dataSet;
        if (mDataSet != null && !mDataSet.isEmpty()) {
            size = mDataSet.size();
        }
    }

    public void refreshData(String add) {
        if (!TextUtils.isEmpty(add)) {
            mDataSet.add(add);
            size = mDataSet.size();
            notifyDataSetChanged();

        }

    }

    @Override
    public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup viewGroup, int viewType) {
        // Create a new view.
        View v = LayoutInflater.from(viewGroup.getContext())
                .inflate(R.layout.list_item, viewGroup, false);

        return new ViewHolder(v);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder viewHolder, final int position) {
        Log.d(TAG, "Element " + position + " set.");

        viewHolder.getTextView().setText(mDataSet.get(position));
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return size;
    }
}
```

**Activity class**

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private RecyclerView mRecyclerView;
    protected CustomAdapter mAdapter;
    protected LinearLayoutManager mLayoutManager;
    protected ArrayList<String> listString = new ArrayList<>();

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        mRecyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.rcList);
        mLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this);
        mLayoutManager.setOrientation(LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL);
        /**
         *setStackFromEnd true will fill the content(list item) from the bottom of the view
         */
        mLayoutManager.setStackFromEnd(true);
        mLayoutManager.setReverseLayout(true);
        mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(mLayoutManager);
        mRecyclerView.setItemAnimator(new DefaultItemAnimator());
        findViewById(R.id.btnAdd).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                int temp = mAdapter.getItemCount() + 1;
                mAdapter.refreshData("Test text " + temp);
                mRecyclerView.smoothScrollToPosition(mAdapter.getItemCount());
            }
        });
        mAdapter = new CustomAdapter(listString);
        mRecyclerView.setAdapter(mAdapter);

    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your long answer. But, I am already using FirebaseRecyclerAdapter Here's a similar project that also uses FirebaseRecyclerAdapter:  https://github.com/firebase/friendlychat-android/tree/master/android

Answer (score 2):

The simplest way to achieve this would be to load the elements into the Recyclerview in the reverse order to how they are entered in the Firebase Database.

```
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder viewHolder, final int position) {
    Log.d(TAG, "Element " + position + " set.");
    viewHolder.getTextView().setText(mDataSet.get(getItemCount() - 1 -position));
}
```

What this would do is that the item which is inserted last will get displayed at bottom since you are loading the items from top. No need for any change in any of the XMLs or any other code.

I had same issues with Recylerview not resizing itself when the keyboard pops up and therefore I resorted to this method.

All the best!!

Answer (score 1):

I have implemented and here is my Implementation using FirebaseRecyclerView
you need to set this **`setStackFromEnd=true`** and **`setReverseLayout=true`**

[my xml](https://pastebin.com/eKD6muYf)

**Recycler View Holder**

```
public class TestingFirebaseHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

    private TextView mTextView;
    private TextView mTextView2;

    public TestingFirebaseHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        mTextView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.textViewTesting);
        mTextView2 = itemView.findViewById(R.id.textViewTesting2);
    }

    public void setTextView(String text,String text2)
    {
        mTextView.setText(text);
        mTextView2.setText(text2);
    }
}
```

**Testing Class**

```
public class TestingUser {

    public String UserName;
    public String mUid;

    public TestingUser() {
    }

    public TestingUser(String userName, String uid) {
        UserName = userName;
        mUid = uid;
    }
}
```

**Activity Code**

```
private EditText mEditText;
private RecyclerView mRecyclerView;
private FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<TestingUser,TestingFirebaseHolder> mAdapter;
private FirebaseUser mUser;
private DatabaseReference mReference;

    mEditText = findViewById(R.id.testingEditText);
    mRecyclerView = findViewById(R.id.hello_rec);
    mUser = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();
    mReference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
    LinearLayoutManager ll = new LinearLayoutManager(this);
    ll.setReverseLayout(true); // set this
    ll.setStackFromEnd(true); // set this
    mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(ll);

    Query query = mReference.child("Testing").child(mUser.getUid()).orderByValue();



    mAdapter = new FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<TestingUser, TestingFirebaseHolder>(
            TestingUser.class,R.layout.testing_recycler_layout,TestingFirebaseHolder.class,query
    ) {
        @Override
        protected void populateViewHolder(TestingFirebaseHolder viewHolder, TestingUser model, int position) {

            viewHolder.setTextView(model.mUid,model.UserName);

        }
    };

    mRecyclerView.setAdapter(mAdapter);


public void buttonClick(View view) {

        if(!mEditText.getText().toString().isEmpty())
        {
            TestingUser user = new TestingUser("Salman",mEditText.getText().toString());
            mReference.child("Testing").child(mUser.getUid()).push().setValue(user);
            mEditText.setText("");
        }

    }
```

**Result is** 
[link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wyObU.jpg)

Answer (score 1):

Try this, it works for me.

```
mLinearLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this);
mLinearLayoutManager.stackFromEnd(true)
mLinearLayoutManager.isSmoothScrollbarEnabled(true)
mMessageRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(mLinearLayoutManager);
```